# no call to bean when using a4j:commandLink and attribute actionListener

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

Hi I want to use `actionListner` in a `commandLink`.

```
<ui:define name="content">
     <a4j:log/>
     <a4j:form id="home">
     <h:commandLink value="bla" actionListener="#{SearchBean.search }">
        <f:param name="keyWord" value="hello"></f:param>
     </h:commandLink>
//some more JSF
    </a4j:form>
</ui:define>
```

My searchBean code:

```
public class SearchBean {

    public void search(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String myAttribute = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("keyWord").toString();
        System.out.println(myAttribute);
    }

}
```

But there is no call to the bean.
I tried using `f:attribute` and `h:commandLink` instead of a4j but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the blank space at the end of the actionListener function name

Answer (score 0):

Where did you declare your bean?If you didnt pick a spesific name for it,jsf names it in the context as lowering the first character.i.e. #{searchBean}

Comment: the weird thing is that if i remove the command link from a4j:form and put it inside h:form there is a call to search method...